# Mongo conditional $push

Tags: mongodb

I want to push to an array based on a condition relating to the elements already present in the array. This is my document structure:

```json
{'_id': ObjectId('6118d887066a0b17c9a4a531'),
  'array_1': [
    {
      'id': ObjectId('6118d887066a0b17c9a4a530'),
      'array_2': [
        {'value': 43, 'when': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 15, 3, 4, 7, 215000)},
        {'value': 42, 'when': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 15, 2, 4, 7, 215000)},
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

`array_2` is sorted by descending date. Currently I push like this:

```json
new_dicts_list = [{'value': 57, 'when': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 16, 3, 5, 7, 215000)}]

db.collection.update(
  {'_id': item_id},
  {'$push': {'array_1.$[element].array_2': {'$each': new_dicts_list,'$sort': {'when': -1}}}},
  {'arrayFilters': [{'element.id': array_1_id}]}
)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to `$push` only if `value` is different to the `value` immediately preceding it in time (`value`/`time` pairs may not be inserted in order). If `value` is the same, `array_2` should remain untouched.

Comment: how about having an extra field with the latest value, you pushed inside the document that contains the array_2, if you have this value you can add it to the arrayFilters to not update if you have it. If you dont want an extra field, i think you will need like pipeline update, and we dont have a `$sort` array aggregation operator, so it will might need more complicated code.

Comment: @Takis_ The push condition is in fact a little more involved. I have updated the question to reflect this. The value should be pushed only if it is different to the value immediately preceding it in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6233e97df7e3c64c6511e147)

Test is for `{"value": 48,"when": 50}`
To test for another document replace it, and replace the 48,50 in the code with the new values.

**All possible cases**

**case = empty array (add without checking anyting)**

New Membed= `{"value": 43, "when": 50}`

```
Before  
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": []}]}
After    
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 50}]}]}
```

**case = add at first, different value, from the preceding in time member**

New Member= `{"value" : 44 "when" : 110}`

```js
Before   
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}   
After   
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 44, "when": 110}, {"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
```

**case = add at first, same value, from the preceding in time member**

New Member= `{"value" : 43 "when" : 110}`

```js
Before  
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
After  
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
```

**case= add at middle, different value , from the preceding in time member**

New Member= `{"value" : 48 ,"when" : 50}`

```js
Before   
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
After  
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 48, "when": 50}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
```

**case= add at middle, same value , from the preceding in time member**

New Member= `{"value" : 41, "when" : 50}`

```js
Before  
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}  
After  
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
```

**case= add in the end, no need to check the value, there is no member with preceding in time**

New Member = `{"value" : 41 , "when" : 10}`

```js
Before   
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}  
After    
{"_id": 1, "array_1": [{"id": 2, "array_2": [{"value": 43, "when": 100}, {"value": 49, "when": 80}, {"value": 45, "when": 60}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}, {"value": 41, "when": 10}]}]}
```

**Query**

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$eq": 1
  }
},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "array_1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$array_1",
          "as": "m1",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$m1.id",
                  2
                ]
              },
              "$$m1",
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$m1",
                  {
                    "array_2": {
                      "$let": {
                        "vars": {
                          "size_position": {
                            "$reduce": {
                              "input": "$$m1.array_2",
                              "initialValue": [
                                0,
                                -1
                              ],
                              "in": {
                                "$let": {
                                  "vars": {
                                    "index_pos": "$$value",
                                    "m2": "$$this"
                                  },
                                  "in": {
                                    "$let": {
                                      "vars": {
                                        "index": {
                                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$$index_pos",
                                            0
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        "pos": {
                                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$$index_pos",
                                            1
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "in": {
                                        "$cond": [
                                          {
                                            "$lt": [
                                              50,
                                              "$$m2.when"
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          [
                                            {
                                              "$add": [
                                                "$$index",
                                                1
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                              "$add": [
                                                "$$index",
                                                1
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ],
                                          [
                                            {
                                              "$add": [
                                                "$$index",
                                                1
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "$$pos"
                                          ]
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "in": {
                          "$let": {
                            "vars": {
                              "asize": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  "$$size_position",
                                  0
                                ]
                              },
                              "position": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  "$$size_position",
                                  1
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            "in": {
                              "$switch": {
                                "branches": [
                                  {
                                    "case": {
                                      "$eq": [
                                        "$$position",
                                        -1
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                      "$switch": {
                                        "branches": [
                                          {
                                            "case": {
                                              "$eq": [
                                                "$asize",
                                                0
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "then": [
                                              {
                                                "value": 41,
                                                "when": 50
                                              }
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          {
                                            "case": {
                                              "$let": {
                                                "vars": {
                                                  "m3": {
                                                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                                                      "$$m1.array_2",
                                                      0
                                                    ]
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                "in": {
                                                  "$eq": [
                                                    "$$m3.value",
                                                    41
                                                  ]
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },
                                            "then": "$$m1.array_2"
                                          }
                                        ],
                                        "default": {
                                          "$concatArrays": [
                                            [
                                              {
                                                "value": 41,
                                                "when": 50
                                              }
                                            ],
                                            "$$m1.array_2"
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "case": {
                                      "$eq": [
                                        "$$position",
                                        "$$asize"
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                      "$concatArrays": [
                                        "$$m1.array_2",
                                        [
                                          {
                                            "value": 41,
                                            "when": 50
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                ],
                                "default": {
                                  "$let": {
                                    "vars": {
                                      "next_member": {
                                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                                          "$$m1.array_2",
                                          "$$position"
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    },
                                    "in": {
                                      "$cond": [
                                        {
                                          "$eq": [
                                            "$$next_member.value",
                                            41
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        "$$m1.array_2",
                                        {
                                          "$concatArrays": [
                                            {
                                              "$slice": [
                                                "$$m1.array_2",
                                                0,
                                                "$$position"
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            [
                                              {
                                                "value": 41,
                                                "when": 50
                                              }
                                            ],
                                            {
                                              "$slice": [
                                                "$$m1.array_2",
                                                "$$position",
                                                "$$asize"
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Now that _is_ a big query! Unfortunately it is not quite correct as the specification is to `$push` only if `value` is different to the one immediately **preceding** it in time. This code `$push`es based on the value coming after. In your second example of "Add at middle or in the end" the new `{"value": 45,"when": 40}` should replace the old `{"value": 45,"when": 60}` as the new value occurred first (when=40).

Comment: The original specification does not state that the value should be replaced so I will accept the answer if it inserts rather than replaces.

Comment: i made it to add only if the next element(with the smaller "when") has different value, i guess this is what you want, next time if you can give more data in, and the data out after the query

Comment: I am so sorry to say that your code does not work as shown in your examples. "case= add at middle, same value , from the preceding in time member" currently inserts while it should not. Otherwise the code is correct. I appreciate you have already spent a lot of time on this and you are correct that it would have helped if I had given input/output examples like you have. Unfortunately I can't really accept the answer in its current form as the outputs in the test case are not as you have documented.

Comment: dont worry at all : ) i dont do it so you accept it, i just started it and i wanted it to work, i had the new version in aggregate and on update i had the old version, and by mistake i sended you the old-version, now you have version that i used to print the examples, the query is not slow and its working but its complicated(MQL syntax make it look much more), maybe there are alternative solutions with more queries sended or slower, but simpler code